# What is causing - The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have been getting this problem with VS2013 for the past few months.  It happens during debugging and when checking local values etc on a breakpoint:

[image]

I am not at all clear if this is an OOM situation in VS2013 or my code.  Except if it is my code I would expect it to throw an exception.  Google was not my friend and the only close reference to this I can find is [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807816/the-function-evaluation-was-disabled-because-of-an-out-of-memory-exception)

It seems this was closed as unreproduceable. It seems that only this other guy and me have the issue!

On the assumption that it is related to VS2013 I disabled most of the addins without any change.

I would very much appreciated it if anyone can help me fix this since it makes debugging pretty much impossible.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting the same problem: 
[Caught OutOfMemoryException makes debugging difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940201/caught-outofmemoryexception-makes-debugging-difficult)

The problem I had is that an OutOfMemoryException was thrown (and caught), and the debugger freaks out about this a bit.

Try checking if your code catches an OutOfMemoryException (SystemException, or Exception) somewhere.